# Iterate through HTML table based on some parameters

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to get the inner text of my HTML tables through a for loop but I want to base it on some parameters. Below you will see the structure of my HTML Table:

```js
var Row = document.getElementById("exploreTable");
    var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");

    l = Cells.length
    var number = 1
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++, number++ ) {
      console.log(number + ". " + Cells[i].innerText);
    }
```

```html
<table id="exploreTable">
  <TR>
    <td></td>
    <A name="Explore"></A>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="...&searchType=subject">
           Labor market
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="....&searchType=subject">
            Sex discrimination in employment.
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="...&searchType=DifferentType">
            Sex discrimination against women.
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know what to add in order that my code will only iterate to a table td with ul/li/a which contains href attribute containing this: `&searchType=subject`. I want to get the text values "Labor market", "sex discrimination in employement" and "sex discrimination against women". I'm thinking `document.evaluate` but I'm not sure yet where to start or to put the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI,your classes have a missing double quote `"`. And maybe you can use `Cells[i].getAttribute('href')`??

Comment: Define values. Do you mean the texts 'labor market' and 'sex discrimination...', the innerText of the hyperlinks? Or do you need the full html string inside a `<td>` ?

Comment: Hi! Yes 'labor market' and 'sex discrimination'.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

`[attr*=value]`

> Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

```js
var Row = document.getElementById("exploreTable");
var Cells = Row.querySelectorAll("td a[href*='&searchType=subject']");

l = Cells.length
var number = 1
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++, number++ ) {
  console.log(number + ". " + Cells[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<table id="exploreTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      --Ommitted some codes for brevity-- 
   </td>
   <A name="Explore"></A>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    --Ommitted some codes for brevity--
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="...&searchType=subject">
           Labor market -- Philippines
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="....&searchType=subject">
            Sex discrimination in employment -- Philippines.
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ColRow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="DetailLink" href="...&searchType=DifferentType">
            Sex discrimination against women.
          </a>
          <a class="DetailLink"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun! I tried your code into my HTML, I''m getting "undefined". When I run var Row = document.getElementById("exploreTable");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td"); console.log(Cells); it is giving me nodelist hmm..

Comment: @schnydszch, you are having some issues in your HTML, though not sure that would be the reason as the above code snippet shows the code works as expected....

Comment: Yeah saw it in the code snippet. It must be the HTML document that I'm having problem. Just in case, this is my HTML document: http://111.125.73.190:8081/cataloging/servlet/presenttitledetailform.do?siteTypeID=-2&siteID=&includeLibrary=true&includeMedia=false&mediaSiteID=&bibID=20248&walkerID=1557217302177

Comment: @schnydszch, that link really does not help, may be creating a fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/  would help....